# I have created dynamic textviews with data .I am trying to create background like on and off button on click of textview Can anyone tell

Tags: android

```
    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        final TextView textView=new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setPadding(8,20,8,0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textView.setText(arrayList.get(i));
        textView.setId(i+1);
```

relativeLayout.addView(textView);

linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
        }

Comment: provide a detailed view of your problem..!! see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean background like on and off button ?

Comment: Yes sir I want to change color on click of  textview

Comment: Amazing bad description. Please read about Writing question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two ColorDrawable objects:

```
ColorDrawable blue, red;
...
     //inside on create:

     blue = new ColorDrawable(0xFF457BEF); //HEX code for blue
     red = new ColorDrawable(0xFFDC3636); //HEX code for red
```

Add this into your loop:

```
        textview.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            textview.setBackground(blue);
        }
        else {
            textview.setBackgroundDrawable(blue);
        }
```

Implement View.OnClickListener to your activity or fragment, whichever you're using, and then add this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getBackground() == blue) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            v.setBackground(red);
        }
        else {
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(red);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            v.setBackground(blue);
        }
        else {
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(blue);
        }
    }
}
```

All it does is change your textView's color to red if it's blue, and to blue if it's red. This should work

Comment: Yes logic is  working  for  textcolor. I  am looking for  change in background color of textview

Comment: I edited it to change the background, it has to `setBackground` or `setBackgroundDrawable` depending on the device's android version

Comment: Good to know. You should mark the answer as correct so other people witht he same issue will know

Answer (score 1):

Look it is nice [Example of Using Selectable button](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/). I think this will help you.